# Getting Express router name

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

If I have the following Express router snippet how can I write a middleware to get the function name ?

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
....
router.get('/hello', helloWorld);
```

What I need to do is log the function name ***helloWorld***. Given that my API is made up of 20+ such functions I just want to log these using *bunyan* or something similar to audit. Anyway to do this in Express ?

Comment: Middleware has no idea where the request will eventually end up, but you can make Express log how requests are passed through routers using `DEBUG=express:router`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `helloWorld` function you can add a line as

```
var helloWorld = function(req, res, next){
  var funName =  helloWorld.name; // .name holds function name
}
```

or

```
function helloWorld(req, res, next){
  var funName =  helloWorld.name; // .name holds function name
}
```

For more info refer: **[function name](http://www.2ality.com/2015/09/function-names-es6.html)**

### Edit:

Please refer: **[middleware.router](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router)**

Comment: Yes that can be done. But im seeing if theres a way to do it in the middleware. I dont want to go through 20+ functions adding this.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the whole point, check my edit.. let me know if that works